# Xcode - Accessing swift class from nested framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, import

I have an Xcode project, with a nested Framework.
The nested framework contains a Swift class I would like to use, that uses the `@objcMembers public class`.

```
@objcMembers public class SPDetailedStringPicker : UIViewController {

}
```

I want to use this Swift class in my base project.
I've tried many import methods such as using:

```
#import "MyNestedFramework/MyNestedFramework-Swift.h"
```

also tried:

```
#import "MyNestedFramework-Swift.h"
```

but no luck.
The project structure looks like this:

```
- MyProject
  - MyNestedFramework.xcodeproj
    - Classes
      - The Swift class I want to use
  - MyProject
    - Classes
      - The Objective c class I want to use that swift class in
```

Comment: You need to use the `open` access for that, see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

Comment: Tried replacing public with open and still can't access the class

Answer (score 2):

Use `<>` instead of `"`

`#import <MyNestedFramework/MyNestedFramework-Swift.h>`

Comment: Also tried this, I get 'MyNestedFramework/MyNestedFramework-Swift.h' file not found

Comment: have you linked your framework to your target at all?

Comment: yeah my target can access everything else inside the framework, just not the swift classes

Comment: You could also open the generated MyNestedFramework.framework file, and check the folder named "Headers" if the -Swift.h present there or not

Comment: Could be also a project configuration issue. Can't say without having the actual project

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for your help @arturdev - I figured after finding the -swift file was present that it was a header issue, opened up Build Phases -> Headers, and added my .framework file to the project. Now i'm able to import as your answer said, and code completion shows up for the rest of the files in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @arturdev 's suggestions - I managed to fix the issue.
It was suggested to check the compiled frameworks headers under:

```
- MyProject
  - MyNestedFramework
    - Products
      - MyNestedFramework.framework
```

The `MyNestedFramework-Swift.h` header file was being generated. I then opened up the build phases tab under `MyNestedFramework` and opened the `Headers` section, then added the actual `MyNestedFramework.Framework` to the project.

I am now able to use the Swift files from `MyNestedFramework` in my base project by importing:

```objectivec
#import <MyNestedFramework/MyNestedFramework-Swift.h>
```